# How do i unblock a process (Insert Stmt) blocked by a parent process (Insert Stmt) with in a TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, transactions, transactionscope

I have a child `TransactionScope` within a parent `TransactionSope`. The child `TransactionScope` is created, executed, and committed multiple times under the singular parent `TransactionScope`.

The parent TransactionScope takes care of `Insert` a single record into the database while waiting for the the second set of insert statements to complete execution one-by-one.

After completing the first transaction, on the first insert of the child transactions there was a problem. After a whole lot of research since yesterday, I would out now that the process that the second insert is running on is block by the first insert's process.

I found this out by running `SP_WHO2` in sql server with the program was running.

Meanwhile, there is a one-many relationship between the two table involved in the insertion process. The first insert performs it's operation on the parent table while the second will be on the child table.

**Whenever i remove the relationship constraint between the two tables the transaction goes through, but doesn't when the constraint is on**.

**My question is how to unblock the second process which is blocked by the first insert?**

Answer (score 1):

If each TransactionScope is using a different connection, then this is expected and by design.

Now, I'm not an expert in c# but...

- Are you using [DependentTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.dependenttransaction.aspx)
- Otherwise, are you [nesting correctly](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=TransactionScope+nested) (Google)